# How to use selected columns with TOP N in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to do something very simple but I just can't do it. I have a table with a column "Week" which represents the name of the day of the week, Saturday, Monday etc. and COUNT(File_FB[messages.content]) which simply counts the number of messages.

I try to take the day of the week which contains the maximum of messages but it doesn't work, COUNT(FB_file[messages.content] is empty i don't know why

Thanks

```
MeasureMaxWeek = 
  CALCULATE(
    VALUES(FB_file[Week]),
    TOPN(
        1,
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            FB_file,
            "Weekname", File_FB[Week],
            "NbMessages", COUNT(FB_file[messages.content])
        ),
        [NbMessages], DESC
    )
  )
```

I try what i mentionned

Answer (score 0):

You were close:

- Change `VALUES` to `MAX` to ensure only one value is returned.
- Use `SUMMARIZE` instead of `SELECTCOLUMNS` so that it groups (and counts).

```
MeasureMaxWeek = 
  CALCULATE(
    MAX(FB_file[Week]),
    TOPN(
        1,
        SUMMARIZE(
            FB_file,
            FB_file[Week],
            "NbMessages", COUNT(FB_file[messages.content])
        ),
        [NbMessages], DESC
    )
  )
```